# If you really want or wanted to get rich

Tags: grammar, tense, clauses

Let's say you are talking to your friend into getting him rich. And you say:

> "You know what, if you really **want** to get rich, you have to make your way to it, it's not instant."

Or

> "You know what, if you really **wanted** to get rich, you have to make your way to it, it's not instant."

Is this all about the **''if''** clauses, then a past verb tense? I'm just so annoyed, I just usually say **want** and not **wanted** help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both of these sentences will be understood, and generally can mean the same thing.**

---

The potential difference between the two, is that the first (present tense) can potentially focus on the future actions that the person can take - and will be more common when assuming good-faith of the other person.

> If you want to do X, [you can do] Y

Is a simple statement that in order to achieve the outcome they want, there is a course of action they should take. Your tone of voice can of course imply that they *should* have done this, but it's not necessarily implied by the word choice.

---

However, using the past tense gives much more emphasis on the idea that they should have *already* done these things, if that was actually their goal.

> If you wanted to do X, [you should have done] Y

Again, the tone of voice will make it clear whether you are critisizing somebody or not - so it is possible to use this phrase in a well meaning way.

However, the default implication is that you feel somebody *should have* taken the action if they truly wanted to achieve the goal. That is, you're critisizing their lack of action, and possibly questioning their true commitment to the goal.

---

As mentioned, the tone of the conversation will override the implications of either sentence - but they are there and can add additional emphasis to what you're saying.

Comment: Your answer is excellent. One more thing, I just realized, my question is **talk into** (persuade)+ **wanted** (you said **criticize** their lack of action). By and large, this seems a lil' bit unfit right?